# Getting partial text from Web Page using Selenium in Python

Tags: selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

```
driver.get("https://kripalunidhi.org/albums/Sadhana_Shivir_Pad_Vol__25")
time.sleep(5)
text = driver.find_element_by_class_name("scroll-padding").text
file2.write(text)
Getting text of only 7 Songs instead of total 14 Tracks
```

**output :**

```
01
Mohin To Bharoso Hai Tiharo Ree Kishori Radhe
Sushri Priyaswari Devi
02
Aho Hari Haun Patak Avtar
Sushri Suswari Devi
03
Radhe Mohin Charan Kamal Raj Keejai
Sushri Suswari Devi
04
Nath Aba Laaj Tihari Jaat
Sushri Madhuswari Devi
05
Aho Hari! Kab Laun Rahihaun Dooree
Sushri Dr. Bageeshwari Devi
06
Hamari Radhe Ati Bhori Sarkaar
Sushri Madhuswari Devi
07
Dinanath Mohin Kahe Bisare
Sushri Priyaswari Devi
Hamein To Shyam Naam Son Kaam
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to scroll to each element, and make sure to have explicit waits.

**Code :**

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
driver.get("https://kripalunidhi.org/albums/Sadhana_Shivir_Pad_Vol__25")

size = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.song-name")

j = 0
while True:
    try:
        element = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.song-name")
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element[j])
        print(element[j].get_attribute('innerText'))
        j = j + 1
    except:
        pass
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```